# Visualize data from one column

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataframe, visualization, jupyter

Suppose I have a data frame with one column as Gender that contains values like -

```
male
female
female
empty 
male
female
```

How do I visualize this data using matplotlib in form of a bar chart or a pie chart to show the number/percentage of male and females?

Comment: I agree that the question can be seen as bad quality and thus be downvoted; however, I don't understand why people want to close this question. It's neither too broad (because the answer is essentially a single code line), nor is it off-topic (as the answer is only trivial once you know which command to use).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest option is probably to use `value_count` on the column and plot the result as bar chart.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = ["male","female", "female", "empty","male","female"]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns= ["gender"])

df["gender"].value_counts().plot.bar()

plt.show()
```

[image]

It's equally possible to plot a pie chart,

```
df["gender"].value_counts().plot.pie()
plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")
```

[image]

Another option, which allows for more fine tuning, would be to use matplotlib as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = ["male","female", "female", "empty","male","female"]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns= ["gender"])

labels = []
for i, dfi in enumerate(df.groupby(["gender"])):
    labels.append(dfi[0])
    plt.bar(i, dfi[1].count(), label=dfi[0])
plt.xticks(range(len(labels)), labels)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the native Pandas functionality:

```
a = ["male","female", "female", "empty","male","female"]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns= ["gender"])
_ = df.groupby('gender').size().plot(kind='pie', legend=True)
```

[image]